# check button is not connected on my quantity entry on tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

So, this is my code. I want this to be connected to my quantity entry but it's not working. Whenever I check the button the quantity entry is still disabled.

```
Pizza = Checkbutton(root,variable=var12,onvalue = 1,offvalue=0, bg="powder blue",command=chk_Pizza)
Pizza.place(x=160,y=355)
txtPizza=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Pizza)
txtPizza.place(x=195,y=355)


HotDog = Checkbutton(root,variable=var2,onvalue = 1,offvalue=0, bg="powder blue",command=chk_HotDog)
HotDog.place(x=160,y=450)
txtHotDog=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_HotDog)
txtHotDog.place(x=195,y=450)


Wings = Checkbutton(root,variable=var3,onvalue = 1, bg="powder blue",offvalue=0,command=chk_Wings)
Wings.place(x=160,y=555)
txtWings=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Wings)
txtWings.place(x=195,y=555)


Burrito = Checkbutton(root,variable=var4,onvalue = 1, bg="powder blue",offvalue=0,command=chk_Burrito)
Burrito.place(x=160,y=650)
txtBurrito=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Burrito)
txtBurrito.place(x=195,y=650)


Hamburger = Checkbutton(root,variable=var5,onvalue = 1, bg="powder blue",offvalue=0,command=chk_Hamburger)
Hamburger.place(x=445,y=384)
txtHamburger=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Hamburger)
txtHamburger.place(x=480,y=384)


Fries = Checkbutton(root,variable=var6,onvalue = 1, bg="powder blue",offvalue=0,command=chk_Fries)
Fries.place(x=445,y=480)
txtFries=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Fries)
txtFries.place(x=480,y=480)
```

And this right here, whenever I check the Taco or Donut  one by one and down to drink, the buttons are all checking.

```
Tacos = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chk_Taco)
Tacos.place(x=445,y=580)
txtTaco=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Taco)
txtTaco.place(x=480,y=580)


Donut = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chkDonut)
Donut.place(x=780,y=380)
txtDonut=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Donut)
txtDonut.place(x=815,y=380)


Icecream = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chkIcecream)
Icecream.place(x=780,y=470)
txtIcecream=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Icecream)
txtIcecream.place(x=815,y=470)


Cupcake = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chk_Cupcake)
Cupcake.place(x=780,y=585)
txtCupcake=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Cupcake)
txtCupcake.place(x=815,y=585)


Smoothie = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chk_Smoothie)
Smoothie.place(x=1150,y=342)
txtSmoothie=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Smoothie)
txtSmoothie.place(x=1185,y=342)


Coffee = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chk_Coffee)
Coffee.place(x=1150,y=445)
txtCoffee=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Coffee)
txtCoffee.place(x=1185,y=445)


Cocktail = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chk_Cocktail)
Cocktail.place(x=1150,y=550)
txtCocktail=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Cocktail)
txtCocktail.place(x=1185,y=550)


drink = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7,onvalue = 1,bg="powder blue", offvalue=0,command=chk_Softdrink)
drink.place(x=1150,y=655)
txtdrink=Entry(root,font=('arial',8,'bold'),bd=4,width=4,state=DISABLED,textvariable=E_Softdrink)
txtdrink.place(x=1185,y=655)
```

This is not the whole code, my code is so long so I didn't paste the whole code here.

And I have a 2nd question, I want the window to be the front of my system but it's not happening. I used tk, top level for my windows, what should I use for my front window? or is there the right position for this? I mean should it be on top of my whole code? Thanks!

Comment: Please turn the second question into another post, rather than appending it to this post.

Comment: Your last eight Checkbuttons all share the same variable, so they all show the same state.  I have no idea why your Entries are remaining disabled, as you didn't show *any* code that might change their state.  (Note: a *single* runnable example of a Checkbutton, Entry, and related code would have made a much better question than 14 near-identical examples that are too incomplete to test.)

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. We don't need six sets of checkbutton/entry combinations. One or two sets is plenty. You should also consider creating these in a loop.

Comment: Appreciate it all, gentlemen! I'm sorry for my code. I'm just new here. Next time I ask again I will cut the unnecessary code.